# indeterminateDuration does nothing on Material ProgressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar, spinner

I have a ProgressBar, here is its style:

```
<style name="ProgressBarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDuration">10000</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateTint" tools:targetApi="m">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and its xml:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="@style/ProgressBarTheme"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nominee_progress_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nominee_progress_size"
    android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

The `indeterminateDuration` tag does nothing to change the speed of the progress bar. I'm assuming it's because of the Material theme.

Basically, I want to slow the Spinning animation down, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: In indeterminate mode, the progress is ignored and the progress bar shows an infinite animation instead.If this progress bar's style only supports indeterminate mode (such as the circular progress bars), then this will be ignored.

Comment: I'm not asking about progress, I'm asking about duration.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @MikeSpeed? I am having the same problem :(

Comment: Nope sorry @tiago I can't remember what I ended up doing in the end. But if you find a solution please post it here!